# Django Aws Ses email send issue b'Invalid MAIL FROM address provided'

Tags: python-3.x, django, email, smtp, amazon-ses

In my settings.py i have a mail congiguration Like :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST') 
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv('EMAIL_PORT') //465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.getenv('EMAIL_USE_TLS')
```

And in my code i am using like :

```
connection = get_connection(
            host=settings.EMAIL_HOST,
            port=settings.EMAIL_PORT,
            username=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            password=settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD,
            use_tls=settings.EMAIL_USE_TLS,
        )
print('11111111')
print(connection)
print('222222222')
mail = send_mail('diditwork?', 'test message', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [userObj.email], connection=connection)
```

But in Result i am getting the error Like :

```
  File "/var/www/html/gelmeko/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 125, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 867, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (501, b'Invalid MAIL FROM address provided', 'AKI**************')
```

> Can any one please help me related this ?? what i am doing wrong here
> i am sending the mail through AWS SES credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try :-

```
Use EMAIL_PORT = 587` instead of `465`
```